# How secure is my auth system?

Tags: authorization, jwt

I want to use jwt tokens that are validated on my servers and for storing the token I am spliting the token into 2 parts the signature and the payload the signature is stored in an httponly samesite cookie with crsf protection and the payload is stored in workers ( I just read this somewhere randomly if it is not a good practice I will store else where) so how secure is that? And am I doing anything extra like the splitimg of the token?

Comment: 1. Secure against what? 2. How would server validate JWT if only signature is present?

Comment: @metallurg secure against exploitation and yeah I did not register that if the cookie is http only then how I am going to reed it and send in headers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your system has a lot of complexity, and you haven't explained why you need that complexity.

[JWTs kind of suck as session tokens.](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens) That is a rather bold statement, but it can be backed up with facts. First of all, the only real benefit of a JWT is that the entity, which first creates (signs) the token, and the entity, which then verifies the validity of the token, can be two different entities. Unless this is one specific use-case of yours, you don't need JWTs.

The promise of "you can validate the JWT without hitting the database" is also kind of untrue, because unless your application doesn't have a functional logout system, you will need to have to add the JWTs ID to a blacklist in order to invalidate it before expiry. Oh, and there is also the fact that *every other operation in your app also has to hit the database*.

So JWTs add a lot of complexity to the system, specifically when it comes to early invalidation (aka. logging out), key rotations, etc.. By comparison, a session token is a randomly generated string, which is stored in an in-memory table and checked against on every call. You will likely be better off with a "traditional" session token.

#### To answer the question

You're not here to have me tell you that JWTs suck, you're here because you want to know if the system you've built can be exploited.

In short, **it makes no sense**. Storing the token in two different places, one of which is insecure, doesn't help at all. There is no benefit to doing that. In order for a JWT to be validatable, both the payload and the signature (as well as the head) need to be present. So merely sending one or two of these three components won't do anything for you.

Further, HTTPonly cookies with Secure- and SameSite-flags set are very difficult for an attacker to exploit. So storing the whole JWT there should work just fine.

#### To summarize:

The best thing to do would be to throw away the complexity of JWTs altogether unless you have *a really good reason to use JWTs*. If the only reason you use them is because they're "so trendy right now", then you're better off just using boring old sessions.

The second best thing to do is to store your JWT in a hardened cookie and treat it like a boring old session.

Comment: Thank you so much this answer was complete and answered all my other questions again thanks and yes the complexity is necessary and not just because of trends or stuff like this

Comment: "add the JWTs ID to a blacklist in order to invalidate it before expiry" To a first approximation, nobody in the world does this, because the main reason people use JWTs is to cut down one DB query. I've reviewed hundreds of webapps and never seen such a thing (although I did see a talk once about the possibility of doing so, in emergencies... but the usual fix there is rotate the key instead). Instead, people just make the JWT lifetime very short - single-digit minutes, usually - and use a refresh token (which does require a DB hit, but not as often).

Comment: Many independent applications can use the same JWT. This enables Single-Sign-On. With a randomly generated string that you propose it takes a **huge efforts** to implement Single-Sign-On.

Comment: @no thanks, I have made quite a few programs that did not even use a database but still had acces controle through JWT’s.  If you design everything with a database, even when it’s not needed. That’s you making poor designs. Add to that that there are a plethora of means to invalidate a session with JWT. From CRL. OCSP to invalidating the serial. Also don’t forget it’s the same problem Kerberos has…. Which is from the 1980’s….